# getting details of a person from a database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the details of a person using their id, I have the following code and it's showing me an error.

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? isset($_GET['id']) : "";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `ArtListing` where `id` = $id";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    die("Query failed " . $conn->error);
}

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo  $row["id"] . "." . $row["name"] ;
    }
```

If I use where the id is some random number like it gives me back the details. The error it's showing me is as following

> Query failed You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: Why have you put that code in backticks (``)?

Comment: If that query is throwing an error, then you are probably feeding it a non-integer (assuming the `id` column type is `INT`), presumably with one or more spaces in it. So `$id` probably doesn't hold the value you expect it does. For security and other reasons, you should be using prepared statements instead of variable expansion. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Note that the way you're building your query is unsafe. You're open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work). You should use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the `id` you grabbing is undefined.

You should assign the `$id` variable as:

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : "0";
```

Comment: That is not the problem. An empty string is a perfectly correct value given that the empty string is expected. As we cannot see the database OP has we can't tell them to use 0 as the value

Answer (score -3):

You cannot simply put variable inside a string
You need to properly concatinate it to become a part of a sting as follows

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `ArtListing` where `id` = '".$id."'";
```

You can test this code here
https://www.tehplayground.com/3HcoDppV0jAqdCYP

Take a look at combination of double quotes and single quotes.

Your SQL query string is created as follows

```
SELECT * FROM `ArtListing` where `id` = yourid; <-- incorrect
```

Whereas as per SQL syntax there should be single quotes

```
SELECT * FROM `ArtListing` where `id` = 'yourid'; <-- check single quotes around 'yourid'
```

Comment: This is outright wrong, as using variables inside double quoted string will output their value.